# How to I convert ordinal Variables to dummy variables in Rstudio?

Tags: r

I need to convert some ordinal variables with 10 possible answers into dummy variables for a multivariate regression. 
I tried it with `recode()`, nothing happened.

```
ESS$netincome_REC <- recode(ESS$hinctnta, "c(1,2,3,4,5)=' 1'" )
ESS$netincome_REC <- recode(ESS$hinctnta, "c(6,7,8,9,10)=' 0'" )
ESS$netincome_REC <- as.factor(ESS$netincome_REC)
summary(ESS$netincome_REC)
```

So the answers 1:5 need to be 1 and 6:10 need to be 0.
Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `ifelse()` instead: `ESS$netincome_REC <- ifelse(ESS$hinctnta %in% 1:5, 1, 0)`

Comment: I guess 1, 0 means that I put either 0 or 1 at the end right?

Comment: Yes, I was merely following what you were trying to do in your code.

Comment: Thank u, it worked